# WebMethod is been added like a part of the request, WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have tried to  test my svc service with SoapUI, but when I create the request, the method is been added like a part of him. but is not part of the request.

There's anyone know how to fixed ?

Here is an example of my request

```
<soap:Body>
   <findSchedule> <!--findSchedule is the part that i want to remove-->
     <request>
        ...
     </request>
   </findSchedule>
</soap:Body>
```

This is how the request has to look like.

```
<soap:Body>
   <request>
        ...
   </request>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Did you try hitting the service? What's the error? Please post the stack trace?

Comment: The issue is that i want to remove this node <sch:findSchedule> from the request. This node has been added without being defined in my schema

Comment: I can understand it, can you answer my question?